# Положение элемента input при уменьшении окна

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы в коде тег инпут не съезжал вниз при уменьшении размера окна браузера?

```
<div style="position:absolute;">
<form>input type="search" class="search"><input type="button" value="Search" class="button"></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте установить

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Таким образом:

```
<div style="position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;">
      <form>
            <input type="search" class="search">
            <input type="button" value="Search" class="button">
      </form>
</div>
```

Вот [описание](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space) этого CSS свойства.